# Farming and Aquaponics using the Win 10 IoT Core on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: windows-iot, c#

I'm working on creating some farming and aquaponics code for the Raspberry Pi using C# and the Win 10 IoT core. I was wondering if anyone else out there is doing anything similar.  I intend to have an Azure based back end for analysis. I see a lot of weather station projects and a few things using sprinkler controller systems. I'm mostly interested in looking for different monitoring hardware that would go well with the Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: These sound like great projects Daniel, but this is likely not the best place to discuss them. StackExchange sites are uniformly focused on answerable questions, rather than open-ended discussion. The help centre has guidance on what you [can ask](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), what you [can't ask](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and [how to write a good question for the site](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). For a less constructed format, I'd recommend trying the [raspberrypi.org forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/).

Comment: I have the exact same project, did you manage to progress on this ? Happy to collaborate, am an experienced C# developer. Best, Fred

Answer (score 1):

I am going with this part of the question as it seems to be the most answerable:

> I'm mostly interested in looking for different monitoring hardware that would go well with the Raspberry Pi 3.

Have a good look at [adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/categories/105) both the shop (disclaimer: no affiliation) as well the extensive guides section. They (and other vendors of course) offer a wide variety of HATs to interface input/output devices and an huge amount of different sensor to interface to. I think it's best to get a feeling what is available first and what can be done with it to work out the specifics of what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I am going with this part of the question...

> I'm working on creating some farming and aquaponics code for the
>   Raspberry Pi using C# and the Win 10 IoT core.

Go and look at all the projects available at the Microsoft IoT developers section for Raspberry Pi

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot

https://microsoft.hackster.io/en-US